# A huge time to download the weights of deep networks

Tags: python, keras

Hi I feel that there is something wrong with the way my code is running. I'm trying to load vgg and resnet for deep learning. This is the code I used.

```
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense

# path to the model weights files.
weights_path = '../keras/examples/vgg16_weights.h5'
top_model_weights_path = 'fc_model.h5'
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'cats_and_dogs_small/train'
validation_data_dir = 'cats_and_dogs_small/validation'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

# build the VGG16 network
model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print('Model loaded.')

# build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
# classifier, including the top classifier,
# in order to successfully do fine-tuning
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

# add the model on top of the convolutional base
model.add(top_model)

# set the first 25 layers (up to the last conv block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model with a SGD/momentum optimizer
# and a very slow learning rate.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

# fine-tune the model
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

At the line 'model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)'
programs starts to download weights and it displays as below.

[image]

This process would take around 5/6 days to complete fully. But it gets stuck at the middle. Is there a simple way that I can avoid this complete process. Manually downloading. Is there something I'm missing.

Please help

Comment: The URL is in the messages, try manual download

Comment: Its a 500 MB file, your internet connection could just be slow to download it.

Comment: Hi Thanks..Yes may be. I could manually download it. Bit how can I use  the parameters such as 'include_top=False'  when manually downloaded.

Comment: @user3789200 There should be 2 different files at the mentioned download location. One file does include everything --> use that file with the flag "include_top=true" and another file that does not include the top --> use that file with the flag "include_top  = false". the links to the mentioned files: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 and https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5